# searching the number of times the letter s appears in the word Mississippi

Tags: python, function, indexing, return, letter

I am trying to find the number of times the letter "s" appears in the word "Mississippi". Why doesn't my code work? I should get an output of 4.

```
def find(word,letter):
    index=0
    while index <len(word):
        if word[index]==letter:
            return index
            index=index
print (index)


find("mississippi", "s")
```

Comment: What do you think happens, line line by, with that example? Practicing troubleshooting will help you more than someone just telling you the answer. Edit your post to include what you think happens step by step, and I'm sure someone will help point out any mistakes.

Comment: Your code raises a NameError exception. You could also consider using the *str* object's built-in *count()* function

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't added the counter, and the index isn't increasing. I reworked your code:

```py
def find(word,letter):
    index=0
    times=0 #added variable to hold number of times

    while index <len(word):
       
        if word[index]==letter:
            times+=1 #this will increase the counter when the letter is matched
        index += 1 #this will increase the index
    print (times)


find("mississippi", "s")
```

Comment: You can also use a for loop:
my_str = 'Mississippi'
counter = 0
for s in my_str:
 if s == 's':
         counter += 1
print(counter)

Comment: Really grateful!